# Create GroupBy Statements Dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to dynamically re-structure some data to be shown in a treeview which will allows the user to select up to three of the following dimensions to group the data by:

```
Organisation
Company
Site
Division
Department
```

So for example, if the user were to select that they wanted to group by Company then Site then Division...the following code would perform the required groupings.

```
var entities = orgEntities
// Grouping Level 1
.GroupBy(o => new { o.CompanyID, o.CompanyName })
.Select(grp1 => new TreeViewItem
        {
        CompanyID = grp1.Key.CompanyID,
        DisplayName = grp1.Key.CompanyName,
        ItemTypeEnum = TreeViewItemType.Company,
        SubItems = grp1
               // Grouping Level 2
               .GroupBy(o => new { o.SiteID, o.SiteName })
               .Select(grp2 => new TreeViewItem
               {
               SiteID = grp2.Key.SiteID,
               DisplayName = grp2.Key.SiteName,
               ItemTypeEnum = TreeViewItemType.Site,
               SubItems = grp2
                  // Grouping Level 3
                  .GroupBy(o => new { o.Division })
                  .Select(grp3 => new TreeViewItem
                  {
                      DisplayName = grp3.Key.Division,
                      ItemTypeEnum = TreeViewItemType.Division,
                  }).ToList()
               }).ToList()
        })
.ToList();
```

This would give a structre like this:

```
+ Company A
  + Site A
    + Division 1
    + Division 2
  + Site B
    + Division 1
+ Company B
  + Site C
    + Division 2
+ Company C
  + Site D
```

However, this only provides me with on of a large number of combinations.

How would I go about converting this into something that could create the equivalent expression dynamically based on the three dimensions that the user has chosen and so I don't have to create one of each of these expressions for each combination!!?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An intriguing problem.  Choosing a single type for grouping keys and another type for results... makes it is very possible to get what you're asking for.

```
public struct EntityGroupKey
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class EntityGrouper
{
  public Func<Entity, EntityGroupKey> KeySelector {get;set;}
  public Func<EntityGroupKey, TreeViewItem> ResultSelector {get;set;}
  public EntityGrouper NextGrouping {get;set;} //null indicates leaf level

  public List<TreeViewItem> GetItems(IEnumerable<Entity> source)
  {
    var query =
      from x in source
      group x by KeySelector(x) into g
      let subItems = NextGrouping == null ?
        new List<TreeViewItem>() :
        NextGrouping.GetItems(g)
      select new { Item = ResultSelector(g.Key), SubItems = subItems };

    List<TreeViewItem> result = new List<TreeViewItem>();
    foreach(var queryResult in query)
    {
          // wire up the subitems
      queryResult.Item.SubItems = queryResult.SubItems 
      result.Add(queryResult.Item);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Used in this way:

```
EntityGrouper companyGrouper = new EntityGrouper()
{
  KeySelector = o => new EntityGroupKey() {ID = o.CompanyID, Name = o.CompanyName},
  ResultSelector = key => new TreeViewItem
  {
    CompanyID = key.ID,
    DisplayName = key.Name,
    ItemTypeEnum = TreeViewItemType.Company
  }
}

EntityGrouper divisionGrouper = new EntityGrouper()
{
  KeySelector = o => new EntityGroupKey() {ID = 0, Name = o.Division},
  ResultSelector = key => new TreeViewItem
  {
    DisplayName = key.Name,
    ItemTypeEnum = TreeViewItemType.Division
  } 
}

companyGrouper.NextGrouping = divisionGrouper;

List<TreeViewItem> oneWay = companyGrouper.GetItems(source);

companyGrouper.NextGrouping = null;
divisionGrouper.NextGrouping = companyGrouper;

List<TreeViewItem> otherWay = divisionGrouper.GetItems(source);
```

Comment: Another approach is to make 5 Grouper classes (one for each kind of grouping) with a common interface IGroupEntities { List<TreeViewItem> GetItems(IEnumerable<source>) } so they can call each other.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I had tried something similar but there must have been a missing link as I never got this iteration to completion.  I have used your sample as a starter and coded a solution that works perfectly for what I was trying to do.  Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). If this is straight LINQ (not through some DB context such as LINQ2SQL), then this can be done by composing your grouping/selector strings:

```
var entities = orgEntities
    .GroupBy("new(CompanyID, CompanyName)", "it", null) // DynamicLinq uses 'it' to reference the instance variable in lambdas.
    .Select(grp1 => new TreeViewItem
    {
        ...
        .GroupBy("new(SiteID, o.SiteName)", "it", null)
        // And so on...
```

You can probably abstract this into each of the criteria type. The only issue I see is the inner groupings might not be the easiest to compile together, but at least this can get you started in some direction. DynamicLinq allows you to build dynamic types, so it's certainly possible to abstract it even further. Ultimately, the biggest challenge is that based on what you're grouping by, the generated TreeViewItem contains different information. Good use case for dynamic LINQ, but the only problem I see is abstracting even further down the line (to the inner groupings).

Let us know what you come up with, definitely an interesting idea that I hadn't considered before.